# Getting false positives on Avast

Tags: 16.04, package-management, antivirus

I downloaded some **updates** for Ubuntu Xenial **from the main repository** and when I run an antivirus scan with **Avast**, I get over **30 alerts** about different kind of risks, like

```
Win64:Vitro on linux-image-4.4.0-1026-gke_4.4.0-1026.26
Elf:ircbot-d [trj] on eggdrop_1.6.21-4_amd64.deb
Win32:Malware-gen on keepass2\keepass.exe
```

Are these **false positives**? It seems strange to get viruses from the main repository.

Comment: Not a duplicate but probably relevant for further decisions: [Do I need to have 'antivirus software' installed?](/q/10373/175814)

Answer (score 0):

Getting false positives is nothing uncommon. You can still verify the files on [virustotal](https://virustotal.com). I had in the past false positive on busybox binary and within two weeks the definitions were updated and warning went away.

Also there is a possibility to get in touch with Avast by reporting a false positive on their web pages.